# Nginx: Location header sent by PHP redirects withoung changing domain

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I'm having a strange problem here and can't figure the cause. I have a php-script on an nginx server which triggers a redirect to a different (sub)domain on the same server:

For instance:
foo.domain.com/redirect.php
header("Status:301");
header("location:http://www.domain.com/new_url/");

The result is that I'm getting redirected to:
foo.domain.com/new_url

The domain doesn't change at all although my response headers look fine .

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you `die()` ing after the `header()`?

Comment: Also are you sure it's not just the address bar display in the browser? That doesn't necessary change when it encounters a 301

Comment: Just an unrelated note, but you don't need to header() calls to send 301 status, you can do: `header('Location: http://www.domain.com/newloc', true, 301);`

Comment: Yeah the script is dieing afterwards AND it's not that the browser adress bar doesn't change properly. It's really as I described it above.. the redirect partly works, it just sticks to the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the cause for my troubles. Neither Nginx, nor PHP caused the issues. My webservers are behind a loadbalancer running with Pound.

Pound has a feature to rewrite domains inside header redirects (enabled by default). We now turned this feature off and all redirects finally work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Check your containing your site in an iframe,

Some hosts can do this if its free hosting, all so some domains setup allows the site to be contained in an iframe witch would cause the properly your describing

Comment: It's not in an iframe, nor a cheap hosting. It's a bigger cluster with a couple of servers behind a loadbalancer.

Comment: sorry then it was an idea thats the only time its happened to me